# React.JS Cancelling onBlur

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to 'cancel' the onBlur event on a form field. So, basically I prevent the user to leave the field under certain conditions.

I tried to do literally cancel onBlur (in a way that the field woudln't lose focus).
But it looks like onBlur is not cancellable.

Another approach looked logical to me: set the focus back again after the control loses it. So I did this:

```
onActivateField =()=> {
   console.log("ActivateField");
}

leavingField = (e) => {
   this.me.focus();
   console.log("tried to focus control...",this.me);
}

return (
  <input type="text"
    ref = {elem => this.me = elem }
    onBlur = {this.leavingField}
    onFocus={this.onActivateField}>
  </input>)
```

Well this didn't work. And `this.me` is a valid element.

So, I thought that maybe if I had another element X to receive the focus, I could interpret the onFocus of element X as losing focus on my field.

I tried with a div, like this:

```
onActivateField =()=> {
   console.log("ActivateField");
}

leavingField = (e) => {
   this.me.focus();
   console.log("tried to focus control...",this.me);
}

return (
   <div onFocus={this.leavingField}>
     <input type="text"
       ref = {elem => this.me = elem }
       onBlur = {this.leavingField}
       onFocus={this.onActivateField}>
     </input>
   </div>)
```

of course, this woudln't work - the `<input>` is **inside** the `<div>`, so its `onFocus` will be triggered when the input's `onFocus` is triggered.

Then I added a dummy `<button>` et voilà it worked!

```
      return (
        <div onFocus={this.leavingField}>
          <input type="text"
              ref = {elem => this.me = elem }
              placeholder={this.props.placeholder} 
              required={isMandatory}
              onFocus={this.onActivateField}
              ></input>
          <button></button> //<-- empty button
        </div>
      )
```

First I added the `onFocus` on the `button` and it worked, but then went back and added it again on the `div`.

You will see that this will work perfectly. But the button is not good for my solution, because I want the user to be able to tab around between fields accross the site without setting focus on any dummy control on the middle.

Also setting `display:none` on the button is not usefull because then it won't receive focus anyway.

But, if I remove the button, puff! It goes back to nothing. Any suggestions?

Thanks! I'll keep experimenting, I'll let you know if I find out a way.

EDIT:
I have found a way that works partially, having an extra control in the div. It works good if you `<TAB>` out of the field, but it doesn't work in other situations (like clicking somewhere else on the page). I am still going for it. If this question must be closed, it's ok. If it's still open by the time I have an answer, I'll post it.